# Filter Dataframe by Boolean Dataframe to insert NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to filter a `data.frame` by another `data.frame` to insert `NA` values. The missing part in here is how to do this without the loop. I think the simplified example below should be self-explaining:

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(214)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

mydata <- tibble(V1 = runif(100), V2 = runif(100), V3 = runif(100), V4 = runif(100))
myfilter <- tibble(F1 = runif(100), F2 = runif(100), F3 = runif(100), F4 = runif(100))

fltr <- myfilter > 0.8
mydata_filtered <- mydata

for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
  mydata_filtered[i, which(fltr[i,])] <- NA
}
```

There are a lot of similar questions answered but I cannot get the clue how to insert the desired NA-Values without using a loop. Most of the answered questions deal with distinct columns or rows, or the required result is just a subset of the originally `data.frame`.

So, the output would be like that:

```
> mydata
# A tibble: 100 x 4
      V1      V2    V3    V4
   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.320 0.332   0.705 0.975
 2 0.932 0.592   0.653 0.526
 3 0.516 0.00137 0.848 0.983
 4 0.420 0.751   0.189 0.742
 5 0.842 0.837   0.588 0.166

> fltr
          F1    F2    F3    F4
  [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  [5,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# A tibble: 100 x 4
       V1       V2     V3     V4
    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.320 NA        0.705 NA    
 2  0.932  0.592    0.653 NA    
 3  0.516  0.00137  0.848  0.983
 4 NA     NA        0.189  0.742
 5  0.842 NA       NA      0.166
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
mydata[fltr] <- NA
```

Comment: Or use `replace` if the OP doesn't want to change the original object `mydata %>% replace(fltr, NA)`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it did not work. Seems to me the problem was sitting in front of the computer. Thanks! Thanks for the `replace` call. In did not know that one.